# Improving performance of appending rows to a data.table

Tags: xml, r, data.table

I'm parsing a bunch of XMLs with similar table-like data and want to join them into a single data.table to do my calculations afterwards. I use `XML` package for parsing, there are ~10,000 xml files to be parsed and each would have 15-150 rows inside (exact number I don't know in advance). My current approach is:

```
sol <- data.table()
for(i in seq_len(length(xml_list))) {
  i.xml <- xmlParse(xml_list[[i]]
  i.component <- as.data.table(xmlToDataFrame(..))
  sol <- rbindlist(list(i.component,sol),use.names=T,fill=T)
}
sol
```

This process takes about an hour on my data. Could somebody point me towards a way to substantially improve performance of this parsing?

Possible ways that I'm thinking are: somehow pre-allocate memory for the larger data.table and append rows instead of re-copying the whole thing on each step? Or maybe there's a faster XML parser that I could use? Or possibly parse XMLs in the list simultaneously and not sequentially (since they are all alike).

Comment: any way to post one of the XML files or is it restricted data?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, unfortunatelly its resticted. Regarding the structure, the nodes i'm after are a few steps into the tree, values i'm looking for are within tags, not attributes. Also some columns are strings and some are numeric. I could try to provide more detail if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

You are recursively `rbinding` your growing `data.table` with each new small addition (10,000+ calls to `rbindlist`!). Better to create a long list of data.tables and then call `rbindlist` once:

```
ll <- lapply( xml_list , function(x) as.data.table( xmlParse( x ) ) )
dt <- rbindlist( ll )
```

I imagine in this format the majority of your processing time is going to be spent reading and parsing the xml files.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, this shaved about 20 minutes off my processing time. Any suggestions as to improving the speed of XML parsing?

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta I'm afraid I'm not so familiar with the xmlParse function or package. I guess you'd need to look directly into the function to see if you could speed that part up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done profiling to see where the time is going?  I would think that most of the time is in the conversion of the XML to a data.table.  Do you need all the data in the XML as part of the data.table?  It would be useful to see an example of the XML where you 'mask' out your private data so we can understand why you are doing with you are doing.

I always ask "tell me what you want to do, not how you want to do it."  There may be other, faster ways of doing it, but without data it is hard to make suggestions.