# R: how to load a small subset of a large zipped xml file?

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing, zip, dplyr

I have a fairly large zipped `xml` file such as `myfile.xml.gz`

I would like to load a small subsample of the file, but I was not able to find some `nrows` options in either `xml2::read_xml` or `XML::xmlTreeParse`.

Trying to open the whole file directly just crashes my computer (the file is too big).

How can I just load a subset of the xml file into a dataframe?

Comment: maybe `readr::read_lines(..., n_max = n)` not sure it will work for your xml situation, but it works with zipped files

Comment: @NathanDay thanks for your input. Unfortunately, reading the first `n` lines with `read_lines` and then feeding the input to `read_xml` does not work...

Comment: it appears it is not that simple. XML have tags so, somehow, the loader needs to parse all these tags before filtering the data. Problem is, my xml file is too big. I cannot believe there is no solution in R for that..

Comment: why the downvote???!

Comment: [Using SAX](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.5/topics/xmlEventParse) ([see also here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31014005/1992669)) won't load everything into memory but will be a bit trickier to use.

Comment: thanks @DavidDuponchel. Can you work out a simple example and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [xmlEventParse](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/XML/versions/3.98-1.5/topics/xmlEventParse) to read the xml in a SAX way.

Let's take the following xml file:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id>l001</id>
    <qty>1</qty>
    <price>10</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>l002</id>
    <qty>100</qty>
    <price>10</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>l003</id>
    <qty>5</qty>
    <price>12</price>
  </item>

  [...]

</items>
```

We will use the event parser to avoid loading everything into memory with the "hybrid mode", loading each `item` as a tree (using `branches` instead of `handlers`). Reusing https://stackoverflow.com/a/31014005/1992669, this gives:

```
library(XML)

input <- "input.xml"
items <- NULL
maxItems <- 50

parseItem = function (parser, node, ...) {
  children <- xmlChildren(node)
  items <<- rbind(items, sapply(children, xmlValue))
  if (nrow(items) == maxItems) {
    xmlStopParser(parser)
  }
}

# with XMLParserContextFunction, we get the parser as first parameter
# so we can call xmlStopParser
class(parseItem) = c("XMLParserContextFunction", "SAXBranchFunction")

xmlEventParse(input,
              branches = list(item = parseItem),
              ignoreBlanks = T
              )

items <- as.data.frame(items)
```